# Is .net framework free

Tags: asp.net

Is .net framework free, If i want to develop a website using asp.net do i need to purchase a license to deploy my website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the .NET framework 'open source' ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961473/is-the-net-framework-open-source)

Comment: I found the duplicate of this question simply by typing the title into the "Search"  box. It was on the first page of results.

Comment: @John I don't really think it's a duplicate, as Open Source <> Free. A technology may be closed source but still free (as in: No Monetary Cost)

Comment: @Michael: read the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Framework itself is free, but ASp.net Websites are usually hosted on a Windows Server which needs licensing.

The alternative ([Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) on Unix/Linux) is free but the tooling and compatibility isn't the same as Microsoft .net.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment can be similar to other hosting services in that you can pay for shared hosting for asp.net similar to other technologies.

If you want to deploy on your own server you do need your own licensee of windows. However, you can use Virtual Private Servers for fairly cheaply compared to linux servers.

Hosting asp.net isn't as hard as it used to be, or as expensive.